# add column to existing dataframe from widgets values using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have a dataframe where i need to add a column from the widget value that is being passed. I am trying the below code but its not helping in anyways. When we display(pdf) we should also see the ID column has also been added.

```
  pdf=pTF.withColumn('ID',lit(dbutils.widgets.text("ID", "eiheifhj", label="pro_ID")).cast(StringType()))
```

The above code is puhsing all nulls into the columns ID. Could you please help. I would request the experts to help in the above challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, you are actually defining the widget instead of fetching the value the widget contains.

```
dbutils.widgets.text("ID", "eiheifhj", label="pro_ID")
```

- "**ID**" is the **name** of your widget.
- "**eiheifh**j" is the **default value** of the widget.
- "**pro_ID**" is the widget **label in UI**

so if you want to fetch the value of the 'ID' widget, you can use the following method.

> dbutils.widgets.get(<widget_name>)

hence your program should be modified as follows :

```
pdf=pTF.withColumn('ID',lit(dbutils.widgets.get("ID")).cast(StringType()))
```